# Issues while creating a view using SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create a view vw_contacttypedetails for

a.  ContactTypeId, Name from person.contacttype

b.  BusinessEntityId, PersonId from person.businessentitycontact

c.  Join both the tables, resulting in the final display of 4 columns (2 from each table as mentioned)

d.  THEN, run a query to see the data in vw_contacttypedetails

I attempted but got an invalid object name. Below is my query:

```
create view vwcontacttypedetails
as
select ContactTypeID,Name,BusinessEntityID,PersonID
from tblContacttype
join tblbusinessentitycontact
on Contacttype.ContactTypeID = businessentitycontact.ContactTypeID
```

Comment: Which object name is invalid?  Why do you think it should be valid?

Comment: @Shobana Would you please elaborate your question more clearly? At least, Put some error logs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your join statement is wrong...

```
create view vwcontacttypedetails
as
select c.ContactTypeID,b.Name,b.BusinessEntityID,b.PersonID
from tblContacttype c
join tblbusinessentitycontact b
on c.ContactTypeID = b.ContactTypeID
```

For how the syntax of joins works, have a look here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

And from the official Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017

> Specifying the join conditions in the FROM clause helps separate them from any other search conditions that may be specified in a WHERE clause, and is the recommended method for specifying joins. A simplified ISO FROM clause join syntax is:

```
FROM first_table join_type second_table [ON (join_condition)]
```

> join_type specifies what kind of join is performed: an inner, outer, or cross join. join_condition defines the predicate to be evaluated for each pair of joined rows. The following is an example of a FROM clause join specification:

```
FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor JOIN Purchasing.Vendor
     ON (ProductVendor.BusinessEntityID = Vendor.BusinessEntityID)
```

> The following is a simple SELECT statement using this join:

```
SELECT ProductID, Purchasing.Vendor.BusinessEntityID, Name
FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor JOIN Purchasing.Vendor
    ON (Purchasing.ProductVendor.BusinessEntityID = Purchasing.Vendor.BusinessEntityID)
WHERE StandardPrice > $10
  AND Name LIKE N'F%'
GO
```